# Can squid proxy's cache overflow?

Tags: caching, reverse-proxy, squid

I have setup squid with 10GB HOT_CACHE aka RAM and 20GB secondary CACHE "on disk".
My system will be making a lot of HTTP request, and i suppose my full cache will get filled in a day or two.

Will i need to stop squid and manually delete "cache dir"?? Or does Squid handles cache overflow by cleaning cache??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i got the answer for my question.

Squid uses LRU cache replacement policy to discard old/unused cache objects.

http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/cache_replacement_policy/